# How to watch env file changes in vite js on static build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have like this configuration file in my vue.js + vite.js project:

File `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

const generateScopedName = 'tw_[local]'

export default ({ mode }) => {
    process.env = {...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')};
    return defineConfig({
        define: {
            'process.env': process.env
        },
        build: {
            sourcemap: false,
            cssCodeSplit: false,
            rollupOptions: {
                output: {
                    dir: 'dist',
                    chunkFileNames: '[name].js'
                }
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
            }
        },
    
        server: {
            fs: {
                allow: ['..'] 
            },
            hmr: {
                overlay: false
            }
        },
        plugins: [vue(), svgLoader()],
        css: {
            modules: {
                generateScopedName
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I build my project by running command `vite build` then value of defined `process.env` variable will be saved as static value from current `.env` file values. But when I put my bulded projec to another place with different `.env` file then value of defined `process.env` won't update automatically. How I can correctly watch `.env` file values for changes on static build if it possible of course?